# what is a gradlew.bat alternative/solution on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, gradle, gradlew, minecraft-fabric

I'm following a Minecraft modding tutorial and they are using a gradlew.bat file which, as I am on macOS, I cannot run it. is there a workaround or alternative other than just switching machines and doing it on Windows or a virtual machine?

Comment: `gradlew`, it can be beneficial to look at the directory after running `gradle wrapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an executable `gradlew` shell script which you can run from the command line, analogous to `gradlew.bat` on Windows.

Comment: It's probably just called `gradlew`, not `gradlew.sh`, if memory serves. And for context, here's some docs for the [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Comment: @Sam arg, indeed. Old habbits die hard :-( Thanks for noticing!